# Unable to find directory using chrome/firefox

Tags: permissions, browser

I don't know if this is a permission thing or what, but I have a directory in root `/` that is not showing up in neither firefox nor chromium and I don't know what's up.

Basically, when I go to `file:///` on firefox and look for the directory `sage`, it doesn't appear. But when I type `ll` into `/` I get the following:

```
drwxrwxr-x   7 root mbbxkad4 4.0K May 11 2023 10:56 sage/
```

So I know it's there, but for some reason it's not showing up. It seems like any directory I create in `/` doesn't appear in  `file:///`. I feel like it's something obvious, but I can't seem to find what the issue is. File permissions seem ok. Any guidance would be nice.

(Note that I can open the file I want if I do `ctrl + o` and literally go to the file using the open file option. So I know firefox has access to the directories in some sense, but when I do that it actually opens the file: `file:///run/user/1000/doc/a651253c/index.html` and isn't actually going into the directory `sage`.)

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 if that changes anything.

**Edit:** From the comments it seems as though it's snap that is sandboxing both chrome and firefox and therefore I don't have access to these files. For the moment I've decided to use opera as that doesn't use snap.

Comment: Firefox is most likely because you are running the Snap package and the sandbox it runs in **REALLY** doesn't want you loading local content. How did you install chrome?

Comment: It is possible that your problem is that there is no 'automatic' system to navigate in a directory tree. You need some special software for that purpose.

Comment: ah, I'm assuming it's a snap thing then as I am using snap for firefox. Is there a way around it? I normally just install chrome from apt, but I recently switched to 22.04, so it might have switched to snap like firefox did if that's the default behaviour?

Comment: I just ran `apt show chromium-browser` and it seems chrome is definitely using snap as well. I'll look into snap and getting around the sandboxing then. Thanks.